# How to create a phase plot for a 2D array of complex numbers with matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, multidimensional-array, complex-numbers

Is there any good way how to plot 2D array of complex numbers as image in mathplotlib ?

It makes very much sense to map magnitude of complex number as "brightness" or "saturation" and phase as "Hue" ( anyway Hue is nothing else than phase in RBG color space).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

But as far as I know imshow does accept only scalar values which are then mapped using some colorscale. There is nothing like ploting real RGB pictures?

I thing it would be easy just implement a version which accepts 2D array of tuples (vectors) of 3 floating point numbers or ndarray of floats of shape [:,:,3]. I guess this would be generally usefful feature. It would be also usefull for plotting real RGB colord images, such as textures outputted from OpenCL

Comment: See this answer for another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17113417/907575

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this does almost the same of @Hooked code but very much faster.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi
import pylab as plt
from colorsys import hls_to_rgb

def colorize(z):
    r = np.abs(z)
    arg = np.angle(z) 

    h = (arg + pi)  / (2 * pi) + 0.5
    l = 1.0 - 1.0/(1.0 + r**0.3)
    s = 0.8

    c = np.vectorize(hls_to_rgb) (h,l,s) # --> tuple
    c = np.array(c)  # -->  array of (3,n,m) shape, but need (n,m,3)
    c = c.swapaxes(0,2) 
    return c

N=1000
x,y = np.ogrid[-5:5:N*1j, -5:5:N*1j]
z = x + 1j*y

w = 1/(z+1j)**2 + 1/(z-2)**2
img = colorize(w)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: When you do c.swapaxes(0,2) you’re altering the orientation of the original image. I needed an additional swapaxes(0,1) afterwards for my image to render correctly. However, I used meshgrid instead of ogrid, as I don’t know exactly how the latter works; perhaps this made a difference?

Comment: @Adarain Or we change line 15 from `c = c.swapaxes(0,2)` to `c = c.transpose(1,2,0)`

Comment: [Further vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77331215/10133797)

Answer (score 11):

Adapting the plotting code from `mpmath` you can plot a numpy array **even if you don't known the original function** with numpy and matplotlib. If you do know the function, [see my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17047989/249341) using `mpmath.cplot`.

```
from colorsys import hls_to_rgb

def colorize(z):
    n,m = z.shape
    c = np.zeros((n,m,3))
    c[np.isinf(z)] = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    c[np.isnan(z)] = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

    idx = ~(np.isinf(z) + np.isnan(z))
    A = (np.angle(z[idx]) + np.pi) / (2*np.pi)
    A = (A + 0.5) % 1.0
    B = 1.0 - 1.0/(1.0+abs(z[idx])**0.3)
    c[idx] = [hls_to_rgb(a, b, 0.8) for a,b in zip(A,B)]
    return c
```

From here, you can plot an arbitrary complex numpy array:

```
N = 1000
A = np.zeros((N,N),dtype='complex')
axis_x = np.linspace(-5,5,N)
axis_y = np.linspace(-5,5,N)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(axis_x,axis_y)
Z = X + Y*1j

A = 1/(Z+1j)**2 + 1/(Z-2)**2

# Plot the array "A" using colorize
import pylab as plt
plt.imshow(colorize(A), interpolation='none',extent=(-5,5,-5,5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot! It is quite slow, so it would be better if there would be such function directly hardcoded numpy (I mean something accelerated in the same way as other array operations in numpy - without iterating over array by python loop ). But the important is that it works.

Comment: @ProkopHapala Actually most of the work _is_ done with numpy, except for the call to `hls_to_rgb` which you could probably vectorize. You can make it _much much_ faster by changing the number of points `N`, the speed should be proportional to N^2.

Answer (score 8):

The library [`mpmath`](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) uses `matplotlib` to produce beautiful images of the complex plane. On the complex plane you usually care about the poles, so the argument of the function gives the color (hence poles will make a spiral). Regions of extremely large or small values are controlled by the saturation. From the docs:

> By default, the complex argument (phase) is shown as color (hue) and
>       the magnitude is show as brightness. You can also supply a
>       custom color function (*color*). This function should take a
>       complex number as input and return an RGB 3-tuple containing
>       floats in the range 0.0-1.0.

Example:

```
import mpmath
mpmath.cplot(mpmath.gamma, points=100000)
```

[image]

Another example showing the [zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), the trivial zeros and the [critical strip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Zeros.2C_the_critical_line.2C_and_the_Riemann_hypothesis):

```
import mpmath
mpmath.cplot(mpmath.zeta, [-45,5],[-25,25], points=100000)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks nice, however it's just for plotting functions where I know analytinc prescription. It is not my case. 

I need something to plot complex data with dicrete sampling which I read from text file and store in 2D narray. I don't have explicit functionoal prescription for this data which could be sampled in any point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `matplotlib.colors.hsv_to_rgb` instead of `colorsys.hls_to_rgb`. The `matplotlib` function is about 10 times faster! See the results below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb
import time

def Complex2HSV(z, rmin, rmax, hue_start=90):
    # get amplidude of z and limit to [rmin, rmax]
    amp = np.abs(z)
    amp = np.where(amp < rmin, rmin, amp)
    amp = np.where(amp > rmax, rmax, amp)
    ph = np.angle(z, deg=1) + hue_start
    # HSV are values in range [0,1]
    h = (ph % 360) / 360
    s = 0.85 * np.ones_like(h)
    v = (amp -rmin) / (rmax - rmin)
    return hsv_to_rgb(np.dstack((h,s,v)))
```

here is the method of picked answer by @nadapez:

```
from colorsys import hls_to_rgb
def colorize(z):
    r = np.abs(z)
    arg = np.angle(z) 

    h = (arg + np.pi)  / (2 * np.pi) + 0.5
    l = 1.0 - 1.0/(1.0 + r**0.3)
    s = 0.8

    c = np.vectorize(hls_to_rgb) (h,l,s) # --> tuple
    c = np.array(c)  # -->  array of (3,n,m) shape, but need (n,m,3)
    c = c.swapaxes(0,2) 
    return c
```

Testing the results from the two method with 1024*1024 2darray:

```
N=1024
x, y = np.ogrid[-4:4:N*1j, -4:4:N*1j]
z = x + 1j*y

t0 = time.time()
img = Complex2HSV(z, 0, 4)
t1 = time.time()
print "Complex2HSV method: "+ str (t1 - t0) +" s"

t0 = time.time()
img = colorize(z)
t1 = time.time()
print "colorize method: "+ str (t1 - t0) +" s"
```

This result on my old laptop:

```
Complex2HSV method: 0.250999927521 s
colorize method: 2.03200006485 s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PIL.image to convert it

```py
import PIL.Image

def colorize(z):
  z = Zxx
  n,m = z.shape

  A = (np.angle(z) + np.pi) / (2*np.pi)
  A = (A + 0.5) % 1.0 * 255
  B = 1.0 - 1.0/(1.0+abs(z)**0.3)
  B = abs(z)/ z.max() * 255
  H = np.ones_like(B)
  image = PIL.Image.fromarray(np.stack((A, B, np.full_like(A, 255)), axis=-1).astype(np.uint8), "HSV") # HSV has range 0..255 for all channels
  image = image.convert(mode="RGB")

  return np.array(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vectorization of [nadapez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20958684/10133797), x2-3 speedup, below.

The best bet is numba or Cython, but if one's stuck with vectorization, this works better. Note I also divide by `max(abs(z))`, don't recall why, but feel free to remove. I also changed `swapaxes` to make shape `(*s, 3)`, as expected by `plt.imshow`.

#### Function

```py
import numpy as np

ONE_THIRD = 1. / 3.
TWO_THIRD = 2. / 3.
ONE_SIXTH = 1. / 6.

def _v2(m1, m2, m2_m_m1, hue):
    hue = np.mod(hue, 1)
    # masks
    idxs0 = np.where((hue < ONE_SIXTH))
    idxs1 = np.where((ONE_SIXTH <= hue) * (hue < 0.5))
    idxs2 = np.where((0.5 <= hue) * (hue < TWO_THIRD))
    idxs3 = np.where((hue >= TWO_THIRD))

    # masked quantities
    hue_0 = hue[idxs0]
    hue_2 = hue[idxs2]

    m1_0 = m1[idxs0]
    m1_2 = m1[idxs2]
    m1_3 = m1[idxs3]

    m2_1 = m2[idxs1]

    m2_m_m1_0 = m2_m_m1[idxs0]
    m2_m_m1_2 = m2_m_m1[idxs2]

    # compute out
    out = np.zeros_like(m1)
    out[idxs0] = m1_0 + m2_m_m1_0*hue_0*6.
    out[idxs1] = m2_1
    out[idxs2] = m1_2 + m2_m_m1_2*(TWO_THIRD - hue_2)*6.
    out[idxs3] = m1_3
    return out


def hls_to_rgb_vec(h, l, s):
    # compute masks
    l_leq_05 = (l <= 0.5)
    l_gt_05  = np.logical_not(l_leq_05)
    ll_05 = l[l_leq_05]
    lg_05 = l[l_gt_05]

    # compute m2, m1
    m2 = np.zeros_like(l)
    m2[l_leq_05] = ll_05 * (1. + s)
    m2[l_gt_05] = lg_05*(1. - s) + s

    m1 = 2.*l - m2

    m2_m_m1 = m2 - m1

    # compute output
    out = np.zeros(l.shape + (3,), dtype=l.dtype)
    out[..., 0] = _v2(m1, m2, m2_m_m1, h+ONE_THIRD)
    out[..., 1] = _v2(m1, m2, m2_m_m1, h)
    out[..., 2] = _v2(m1, m2, m2_m_m1, h-ONE_THIRD)
    return out
```

#### Test + bench

```py
def colorize(z):
    z = z / np.abs(z).max()
    r = np.abs(z)
    arg = np.angle(z)

    h = (arg + np.pi)  / (2 * np.pi) + 0.5
    l = 1.0 / (1. + r)
    s = 0.8

    c = np.vectorize(hls_to_rgb)(h, l, s)
    c = np.array(c)
    c = c.transpose(1, 2, 0)
    return c

for N in (5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000):
    print(f'\nN={N}')
    z = np.random.randn(N, N + 1) + 1j*np.random.randn(N, N + 1)

    # assert equality
    o0 = colorize(z)
    o1 = colorize_v2(z)
    assert np.allclose(o0, o1, atol=0)

    # bench
    %timeit colorize(z)
    %timeit colorize_v2(z)
```

Only `N=5` is slower on my CPU, by x2.

**Note**: as far as `hls_to_rgb_vec` is concerned independent of `colorize_v2`, `s != 0` is assumed (since for `colorize_v2` it's always `0.8`), and non-scalar `s` isn't tested.