# How to plot complex numbers (Argand Diagram) using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, complex-numbers

I'd like to create an [Argand Diagram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgandDiagram.html) from a set of complex numbers using matplotlib.

- Are there any pre-built functions to help me do this?
- Can anyone recommend an approach?

[image]

<sub>[Image](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Argandgaussplane.png) by [LeonardoG](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:LeonardoG), CC-SA-3.0</sub>

Comment: For phase plots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044052/matplotlib-imshow-complex-2d-array

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after here...you have a set of complex numbers, and want to map them to the plane by using their real part as the x coordinate and the imaginary part as y?

If so you can get the real part of any python imaginary number with `number.real` and the imaginary part with `number.imag`. If you're using numpy, it also provides a set of helper functions numpy.real and numpy.imag etc. which work on numpy arrays.

So for instance if you had an array of complex numbers stored something like this:

```
In [13]: a = n.arange(5) + 1j*n.arange(6,11)

In [14]: a
Out[14]: array([ 0. +6.j,  1. +7.j,  2. +8.j,  3. +9.j,  4.+10.j])
```

...you can just do

```
In [15]: fig,ax = subplots()

In [16]: ax.scatter(a.real,a.imag)
```

This plots dots on an argand diagram for each point.

edit: For the plotting part, you must of course have imported matplotlib.pyplot via `from matplotlib.pyplot import *` or (as I did) use the ipython shell in pylab mode.

Comment: Try to avoid `import *`: it's much more readable and less confusing if you don't import in the current name space and do something like `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and then `plt.`. Plus this avoids you possible name clashes

Answer (score 13):

To follow up @inclement's answer; the following function produces an argand plot that is centred around 0,0 and scaled to the maximum absolute value in the set of complex numbers.

I used the plot function and specified solid lines from (0,0). These can be removed by replacing `ro-` with `ro`.

```
def argand(a):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    for x in range(len(a)):
        plt.plot([0,a[x].real],[0,a[x].imag],'ro-',label='python')
    limit=np.max(np.ceil(np.absolute(a))) # set limits for axis
    plt.xlim((-limit,limit))
    plt.ylim((-limit,limit))
    plt.ylabel('Imaginary')
    plt.xlabel('Real')
    plt.show()
```

For example:

```
>>> a = n.arange(5) + 1j*n.arange(6,11)
>>> from argand import argand
>>> argand(a)
```

produces:
[image: argand function output graph]

**EDIT:**

I have just realised there is also a [`polar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.polar) plot function:

```
for x in a:
    plt.polar([0,angle(x)],[0,abs(x)],marker='o')
```

[image]

Comment: What does `label = 'python'`do in your plot?

Comment: @Ipnorm A while ago now but doesn't do anything by the looks...

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a plot like the one below

[one type of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX4Ad.png)

or this one [second type of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYrde.png)

you can do this simply by these two lines (as an example for the plots above):

```
z=[20+10j,15,-10-10j,5+15j] # array of complex values

complex_plane2(z,1) # function to be called
```

by using a simple jupyter code from here
https://github.com/osnove/other/blob/master/complex_plane.py

I have written it for my own purposes. Even better it it helps to others.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to paste the image directly?

Answer (score 1):

To get that:

[image]

You can use:

- [cmath.polar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.polar) to convert a complex number to polar rho-theta coordinates. In the code below this function is first [vectorized](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) in order to process an array of complex numbers instead of a single number, this is just to prevent the use an explicit loop.
- A `pyplot` axis with its projection type set to [polar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/projections_api.html#module-matplotlib.projections.polar). Plot can be done using [pyplot.stem](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html) or [pyplot.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).

In order to plot horizontal and vertical lines for Cartesian coordinates there are two possibilities:

- Add a Cartesian axis and plot Cartesian coordinates. This solution is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18789157/774575). I don't think it's an easy solution as the Cartesian axis won't be centered, nor it will have the correct scaling factor.
- Use the polar axis, and translate Cartesian coordinates for projections into polar coordinates. This is the solution I used to plot the graph above. To not clutter the graph I've shown only one point with its projected Cartesian coordinates.

Code used for the plot above:

```
from cmath import pi, e, polar
from numpy import linspace, vectorize, sin, cos
from numpy.random import rand
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Arrays of evenly spaced angles, and random lengths
angles = linspace(0, 2*pi, 12, endpoint=False)
lengths = 3*rand(*angles.shape)

# Create an array of complex numbers in Cartesian form
z = lengths * e ** (1j*angles)

# Convert back to polar form
vect_polar = vectorize(polar)
rho_theta = vect_polar(z)

# Plot numbers on polar projection
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.stem(rho_theta[1], rho_theta[0])

# Get a number, find projections on axes
n = 11
rho, theta = rho_theta[0][n], rho_theta[1][n]
a = cos(theta)
b = sin(theta)
rho_h, theta_h = abs(a)*rho, 0 if a >= 0 else -pi
rho_v, theta_v = abs(b)*rho, pi/2 if b >= 0 else -pi/2

# Plot h/v lines on polar projection
ax.plot((theta_h, theta), (rho_h, rho), c='r', ls='--')
ax.plot((theta, theta_v), (rho, rho_v), c='g', ls='--')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *


'''
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
This draws the axis for argand diagram
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
'''
r = 1
Y = [r*exp(1j*theta) for theta in linspace(0,2*pi, 200)]
Y = array(Y)
plt.plot(real(Y), imag(Y), 'r')
plt.ylabel('Imaginary')
plt.xlabel('Real')
plt.axhline(y=0,color='black')
plt.axvline(x=0, color='black')


def argand(complex_number):
    '''
    This function takes a complex number.
    '''
    y = complex_number
    x1,y1 = [0,real(y)], [0, imag(y)]
    x2,y2 = [real(y), real(y)], [0, imag(y)]


    plt.plot(x1,y1, 'r') # Draw the hypotenuse
    plt.plot(x2,y2, 'r') # Draw the projection on real-axis

    plt.plot(real(y), imag(y), 'bo')

[argand(r*exp(1j*theta)) for theta in linspace(0,2*pi,100)]
plt.show()
```

https://github.com/QuantumNovice/Matplotlib-Argand-Diagram/blob/master/argand.py