# Plotting 4D information

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Suppose that I have a function which takes in 2 real numbers `x,y` as input and outputs 2 real numbers `w,z`, i.e., `myfunc(x,y)=w,z`, so if I had a list of `x,y` points, then I would also have a list of `w,z` points. I want to be able to visualize this on plot. One way that I know how is to regard `w,z` as a point in 2d space and calculate the angle `theta` and intensity `r` (convert to polar coordinates) and use scatter plot where I represent the angle `theta` with a hue and intensity `r` with luminous. The following would be a pseudo-code in python

```
w,z  = myfunc(x,y)
theta, r = cartesian2polar(w,z)

cmap = matplotlib.cm.hsv
my_cmap = convert cmap so that theta corresponds to a hue and r is the luminous

plt.scatter(x,y,c=my_cmap)
```

The problem with this is that the scatter plot is relatively slow when I have many data points. Is there anyway else to implement this but much more quickly? Maybe by using `imshow`, since my `x,y` points are actually obtained from `meshgrid`.

**EDIT**:
I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044052/mathplotlib-imshow-complex-2d-array), which does exactly what I need.

Comment: Please try to limit your question to one specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck is computing the cmap.

Could you generate the cmap once and for all? Perhaps could you lower the resolution on the cmap and, instead of having a continuous cmap, have a discrete one.