# OPENCV: Trouble implementing Frankot-Chellappa Algorithm (depth from normal)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to reconstruct surface/depthmap from normals using the frankot/chellappa algorithm.
The rows and cols are the size of the img I'm trying to reconstruct the depth for.

I obtain the normal vectors like this:

```
rows, cols = imglist[0].shape
def find_NormAlbedo(sources, imglist, rows, cols):
    '''
    :param sources: a list of light source coordinates as [x,y,z] coordinates per light source
                    (shape (20,3) for 20 sources)
    :param imglist: a list of all images for one object
    :param rows: shape[0] of every image
    :param cols: shape[1] of every image
    :return: returns normals and albedo's for an object
    '''
    normal = np.zeros_like(imglist[0], dtype=np.ndarray)
    albedo = np.zeros_like(imglist[0])

    # for every pixel
    for x in range(rows):
        for y in range(cols):
            I = []  # intensity matrix of pixel x,y per image
            S = []  # lightsources
            for i in range(len(imglist)):
                img = imglist[i]
                I.append([img[x][y]])
                S.append(sources[i])

            # Least squares solution if S is invertible
            # pseudoinverse
            pseudoS = np.linalg.pinv(S)

            ntilde = pseudoS @ I
            p = np.linalg.norm(ntilde, ord=2)
            if p != 0.:
                n = ntilde / p
                n = n.flatten()
                # print(n)
                # print(n.shape)
            else:
                n = np.zeros_like(ntilde.flatten())

            normal[x][y] = n
            albedo[x][y] = p

    return normal, albedo
```

But suspect it's wrong because my albedo looks completely different from what I've seen in examples but have no clue where my mistake is...

[image]

Then I try to Get the surface from that using a wavepy function surface_to_grad:

```
def depthfromgradient(normalmap):
    '''
    :param normalmap: Previously obtained normals per pixel
    :return: Surface/Depth map from normalmap
    '''
    surfacep = np.zeros_like(normalmap)
    surfaceq = np.zeros_like(normalmap)
    for row in range(rows):
        for x in range(cols):
            #print(x)
            a, b, c = normalmap[row][x]
            #print(a, b, c)
            if c !=0:
                p = -a / c  # p=dZ/dx
                q = -b / c  # q=dZ/dy
                surfacep[row][x] = p
                surfaceq[row][x] = q
    return surface_from_grad.frankotchellappa(surfacep, surfaceq, reflec_pad=True)
```

My goal is to visualise the depthmap and the normalmap with cv.imshow(), but I'm not sure where I went wrong. These are my questions/ideas of where it went wrong:

-Is the albedomap plausible? If no, I think I misunderstood part of this algorithm.

-My depthmap has complex numbers, is this normal? Where do these come from?

-I looked at the shape of the normal map, the albedo map and the depth map, they all have shape (640, 500), yet I can only visualise the albedomap, the others give me the following error, what is the problem here?:

```
cv2.imshow('DepthMap', surface)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'mat'
```

Any help in narrowing down this problem would be welcome.

Note:I have tried converting everything to np arrays before using imshow().

Comment: To me, it looks like you have a range issue.  For example, as if your math were producing values up to 1024, but you're only displaying the low-order 8 bits.  Have you printed some pixel values to see what you're doing to the data?  You might consider converting the pixel values to floating  point in [0,1] before the computations, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Why did you rebuild S for every pixel ? And you have one light source per image ?

Comment: @David You're right, rebuilding S isn't necessary, thanks. Yes, I have 1 object, for which I have 20 images, each with a lightsource.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your reply, My pixel values are all ints, when I start my computations, everything gets converted to float64 (ntilde is float64). When I look at the final normalmap (normal) it stores ndarrays with ndarrays(x,y,z)and albedomap (albedo), stores ndarray with uint8, but I have no issues with that one.

Comment: I will be glad to help you more but without access to your image and the expected result this is difficult. Where did you take your example ? Can you share your image on GitHub or similar site ?

Comment: @David it would be incredibly helpful if you could! https://github.com/KateDelb/ComputerVision/tree/master (I wasn't paying attention so the Readme is in https://github.com/KateDelb/ComputerVision/tree/main).

Comment: The shape of your normal map is (640,500) but each element is a list. `print(normal[0][0])` to see is component. By definition a normal is a vector(x,y,z). You have to convert it in some way to display it as an image.

Comment: Hi David, thank you, I'm mostly still struggling with the visualisation of the surface (which is a 2D array of complex numbers. I tried colorizing them in the following manner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044052/matplotlib-imshow-complex-2d-array but my result makes no sense.

Comment: The normal vector used in `depthfromgradient()`  is not a unit vector is it ok ? Some of the light source in `refined_light.txt` have all negative coordinate so they must come from the back of the image but none of the image seem to be back lighted.

Comment: @David interesting, hadn;t even noticed that. And yes, it doesn't need to be a unit vector I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exactly as I described in my very first comment.  The values you get for `p` (which become your `albedo` image) range from 0 to 1998.34.  When you store that in a byte, you're just getting the low-order 8 bits, which wrap around.

If you change this:

```
            albedo[x][y] = p
```

to this:

```
            albedo[x,y] = p/8
```

you'll see that the resulting image looks great.

By the way, there are several optimizations you can do.  Where you have `xxx[x][y]` with a numpy array, do `xxx[x,y]` instead.  When you build your lightsources, instead of

```
            I = []  # intensity matrix of pixel x,y per image
            S = []  # lightsources
            for i in range(len(imglist)):
                img = imglist[i]
                I.append([img[x][y]])
                S.append(sources[i])
```

do

```
            I = [img[x,y] for img in imglist]
            S = sources[:len(imglist),:]
```

and your `obtainData` function can be made more readable by doing:

```
    # Read all images
    paths = (
     fr".\PSData\PSData\{things[i]}\Objects\Image_01.png",
     fr".\PSData\PSData\{things[i]}\Objects\Image_02.png",
     fr".\PSData\PSData\{things[i]}\Objects\Image_03.png",
     fr".\PSData\PSData\{things[i]}\Objects\Image_04.png",
     fr".\PSData\PSData\{things[i]}\Objects\Image_05.png"
    )

    imgs = [cv2.imread(p,0) for p in paths]
...
    # Apply masks to images: cv2.bitwise
    imglist = [cv2.bitwise_or(img, img, mask=mask(img, threshold)) for img in imgs]
```

Comment: Dear Tim, thank you for your help. The albedo looks much better! I'm still having the issues visualising the surface however. I tried colorizing it using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044052/matplotlib-imshow-complex-2d-array, however, my image is completely lost (I simply get an image that is blue on 1 side, pink on the other side.) Do you have any idea what this might be?

Comment: I didn't dig any further because I didn't want to install `wavepy` and `colorsys`.  My best advice is to check your ranges.  Print the values in `surface`, including mins and maxes, to make sure they really are complex and to find the ranges.  See if the values returned from `colorize` are in the right range.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the documentation of the `wavepy.surface_from_grad.frankotchellappa()` the complex part can be ignored. Base on that they can be displayed with matplotlib to obtain an image like this one :[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
import numpy as np


ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
surface = [[-2.19312825e+00-1.62679906e-02j,-1.76625653e+00-1.62093005e-02j ,-1.21359325e+00-1.63381200e-02j,-5.91501045e-01-1.45226036e-02j ,-9.24685295e-02-1.73373776e-03j, 1.59549135e-01+8.17785543e-05j , 2.90806910e-01-4.70409288e-05j, 3.47604091e-01+1.16492161e-05j],[-2.40280993e+00+1.62679906e-02j,-1.66061279e+00+1.62093005e-02j ,-1.11510109e+00+1.63381200e-02j,-3.08374007e-01+1.45226036e-02j , 1.57978453e-01+1.73373776e-03j, 2.59650686e-01-8.17785543e-05j , 3.63995725e-01+4.70409288e-05j, 4.01138015e-01-1.16492161e-05j],[-2.23283386e+00-1.62679906e-02j,-1.37689420e+00-1.62093005e-02j ,-7.79238609e-01-1.63381200e-02j, 6.13042608e-02-1.45226036e-02j , 4.21894421e-01-1.73373776e-03j, 4.22562434e-01+8.17785543e-05j , 4.81126228e-01-4.70409288e-05j, 4.97191034e-01+1.16492161e-05j],[-2.03380248e+00+1.62679906e-02j,-1.15214942e+00+1.62093005e-02j ,-5.31293338e-01+1.63381200e-02j, 3.06448040e-01+1.45226036e-02j ,6.43854839e-01+1.73373776e-03j, 5.97558594e-01-8.17785543e-05j ,6.18487416e-01+4.70409288e-05j, 6.16102854e-01-1.16492161e-05j],[-1.78298688e+00-1.62679906e-02j,-8.95377575e-01-1.62093005e-02j ,2.76063262e-01-1.63381200e-02j, 5.45799539e-01-1.45226036e-02j ,8.50153479e-01-1.73373776e-03j, 7.66200038e-01+8.17785543e-05j ,7.57462265e-01-4.70409288e-05j, 7.39255327e-01+1.16492161e-05j],[-1.48865585e+00+1.62679906e-02j,-6.06732343e-01+1.62093005e-02j ,2.25981613e-03+1.63381200e-02j, 7.88696843e-01+1.45226036e-02j ,1.04351159e+00+1.73373776e-03j, 9.19975122e-01-8.17785543e-05j ,8.83235485e-01+4.70409288e-05j, 8.50665864e-01-1.16492161e-05j],[-1.20317686e+00-1.62679906e-02j,-3.29863821e-01-1.62093005e-02j ,2.50911348e-01-1.63381200e-02j, 9.99471222e-01-1.45226036e-02j ,1.21789476e+00-1.73373776e-03j, 1.04762150e+00+8.17785543e-05j ,9.81522674e-01-4.70409288e-05j, 9.36002572e-01+1.16492161e-05j],[-7.74950625e-01+1.62679906e-02j, 9.04024675e-02+1.62093005e-02j
  ,6.51399438e-01+1.63381200e-02j, 1.32951041e+00+1.45226036e-02j
  ,1.36765625e+00+1.73373776e-03j, 1.12552107e+00-8.17785543e-05j
  ,1.03744750e+00+4.70409288e-05j, 9.82554438e-01-1.16492161e-05j]]

surface=np.array(surface)
X = np.arange(0,8)
Y = np.arange(0,8)
Z = [surface[x,y].real for x in X for y in Y]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z= np.array(Z)
Z= np.reshape(Z, xx.shape)
colortuple = ('g', 'cyan')
colors = np.empty(xx.shape, dtype=str)
for y in range(len(Y)):
    for x in range(len(Y)):
        colors[y, x] = colortuple[(x + y) % len(colortuple)]

surf = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, Z, facecolors=colors, linewidth=0)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(6))

plt.show()
```