# How to make a bi-variate or 2-dimension colormap with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I am trying to make a geographical map with colors, in which the colors of pixels will depend on 2-dimensions of (x,y), like this one extracted from one publication:

[image: Lowerleft corner is the 2-dimension colorbar legend whose color depends changes of two variables]

I searched online and this is where I arrive:

https://gist.github.com/ChaoYue/81eb01b558f068f11ee741c56557a6a2

To put it short, I know how to pick up color by x-axis value, and use y-axis value as an indicator of either saturation, or brightness or transparency of the color. Or somehow to convert this (x,y) information back to linear space and select color from a matplotlib colormap. But the question is, for example, suppose I want the color as lowerleft=blue,lowerright=green; upperleft=red,upperright=orange. How can I interpolate the color of pixels in between? Or maybe this example is in contradiction with color theory and it is not possible?  The equivalent question is: how can I make a colorbar legend like the figure shown in the above?

These are the online sources that help me, but they don't directly give the instructions I am looking for:

[Is there any way to use bivariate colormaps in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207255/is-there-any-way-to-use-bivariate-colormaps-in-matplotlib)

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4369

Comment: Just to confirm: you want to know how to create a bi-variate colour map from four "corner colours" by linearly interpolating between the corners?

Comment: Basically doing bi-linear interpolation between four colours. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation